# VBA - Loading Multi-Dimensional Array into Listbox Once or Twice a Second

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, listbox

Im using VBA inside Factory Talk, which is a software used for HMI's in automation systems mostly. Factory talk uses tags which are address to data inside a PLC that Factory Talk "talks" to. These tags update rates can be changed from .250 seconds and up.

One screen has a list box that is refilled with new data with an update rate of .750 seconds right now. I retrieve the tags from the PLC, do some formatting, filtering, possibly sorting, then load the data into the listbox from an multi dimensional array by using the command:

```
Listbox1.List = buffer
```

I used a list box this way to allow for sorting on certain columns.

Question: Is there a faster way to load a multidimensional array into a list box? Is a list box even the right control to use for VBA? Keep in mind I am using VBA, not vb.Net. It seems when I keep this screen open for a few hours or days(which is very possible during production) on any of the HMI's the servers memory climbs really high for that user.

The code below is the routine relevant to this question where the data is loaded into the list box.

```
Private Sub LoadDataIntoBuffer()
Application.LogDiagnosticsMessage ("Load DATA INTO BUFFER start - " & DateTime.Now)
Dim i As Integer               'Loop Counter for Tag Groups
Dim c As Integer: c = 0        'Loop Counter for Buffer Array
Dim p As Integer: p = 1        'Counter for Set of Vehicle Data
Dim pathID As String           'To Hold PathID of Vehicle
Dim position As String         'To Hold Position of Vehicle
Dim TagsInError As StringList
Dim ModuleName As String

'Error management
ModuleName = "LoadDataIntoBuffer"
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

'Erase Stored Values in Buffer
Erase buffer

'Iterate Through Each Vehicle and Vehicle Data into Buffer Array
For i = 1 To maxVehicles
    pathID = MMTagGrpVeh.Item(p + 1).Value
    position = Format(Val(MMTagGrpVeh.Item(p + 2).Value), "0.000000")

    'If PathID and Position are not zero, the vehicle is valid. Store in Buffer Array
    If pathID <> 0 And position <> 0 Then
        buffer(c, 0) = "      " & i
        buffer(c, 1) = MMTagGrpVeh.Item(p).Value
        buffer(c, 2) = pathID
        buffer(c, 3) = position
        buffer(c, 4) = MMTagGrpVeh.Item(p + 3).Value
        buffer(c, 5) = TranslateInt(MMTagGrpVeh.Item(p + 4).Value)

        c = c + 1  'Increment Entry Number
    End If
    p = p + 5
Next

entriesInBuffer = c - 1  'Keep Track of Number of Entries in Buffer Array

'If List is Sorted on a Column, Keep it Sorted on that Column After Updating Values
'Barcode
If listIsSorted = 1 Then
    selectionSortString buffer, 1, entriesInBuffer
'Path Id + Position
ElseIf listIsSorted = 2 Then
    selectionSortPathID buffer, 2, entriesInBuffer
'Vehicle Status
ElseIf listIsSorted = 3 Then
    selectionSortString buffer, 5, entriesInBuffer
'Reverse Vehicle ID
ElseIf listIsSorted = 4 Then
    selectionSortReverseInteger buffer, 0, entriesInBuffer
'Reverse Barcode
ElseIf listIsSorted = 5 Then
    selectionSortReverseString buffer, 1, entriesInBuffer
'Reverse PathID + Position
ElseIf listIsSorted = 6 Then
    selectionSortPathIDReverse buffer, 2, entriesInBuffer
'Reverse Vehicles Status
ElseIf listIsSorted = 7 Then
    selectionSortReverseString buffer, 5, entriesInBuffer
End If

Exit Sub




Private Sub LoadDataIntoListBox()
Application.LogDiagnosticsMessage ("LOAD DATA INTO LISTBOX start - " & DateTime.Now)
Dim listBoxArray(numRowsInListBox - 1, numColumns - 1)   'Array to Hold List Box Data
Dim ModuleName As String   'Error Handling
Dim i As Integer           'Loop Counter for Buffer Array
Dim c As Integer: c = 0    'Loop Counter for ListBox Array
Dim index As Integer

'Error management
ModuleName = "LoadDataIntoListBox"
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

'Iterate through the Indexes of the Buffer Array that will be...
'...Shown in List Box and Put the Data in the List Box Array
For i = lowerBound To upperBound
    If i <= maxVehicles Then
        listBoxArray(c, 0) = buffer(i, 0)
        listBoxArray(c, 1) = buffer(i, 1)
        listBoxArray(c, 2) = buffer(i, 2)
        listBoxArray(c, 3) = buffer(i, 3)
        listBoxArray(c, 4) = buffer(i, 4)
        listBoxArray(c, 5) = buffer(i, 5)

        c = c + 1
    End If
Next i

'Get Current Selected Index of List Box
index = ListBox1.ListIndex

'Send Data in listBoxArray into List Box for Display on Screen
ListBox1.List = listBoxArray

'Set Selected Index of List Box to Previously Stored Index
ListBox1.ListIndex = index
Exit Sub
```

Comment: `ListBox1.List = listBoxArray` - that's one instruction, taking an array in memory and copying it in another spot in memory in one single VBA instruction; the listbox will only repaint once... I don't see how a listbox could be updated any faster than that. the slow part seems to be the `For i` loop, which from my outsider eyes really needs a very good reason to even exist. Why can't `ListBox1.List = buffer`?

Comment: I should've explained. Depending on the part of the line the screen is up for, there could be anywhere from 60 to 120 vehicles that have data brought in. So the for loop you brought up only loads 30 of them into the listbox at a time. When I loaded them all into the listbox at a time, there was a split second where the listbox went blank and was loading. Since I am repopulating the list box once or twice a second, this made the screen unusable.

Comment: If your code works as intended, just slower than it needs to be, you should probably be putting it up (all of it, not just "what's relevant" - you'd be surprised with how much "irrelevant" stuff actually matters) on [codereview.se]... including as much additional context as needed for external eyes to assess the situation. =)

Comment: I added the other routine that is fired when the list box updates. I want to bring up I do not believe it has anything to do with the sorting in the LoadDataIntoBuffer routine because by default, it is unsorted, and I still have the high memory issue. Thanks for the reply. If you have any more questions, please ask. Some of the instructions I use are due to the way Factory Talk works with the tags from the PLC and how I need to handle them.

Comment: I'd just dump the whole module on a fresh [codereview.se] post, and take the time to *present* that code to the reviewers, *describe* its purpose, what it does, how it does it and why it does it that way; "how can I optimize my code" is really *too broad* for Stack Overflow, but exactly in-scope for Code Review. [Check it out!](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I did not want anyone here to comb through all of my code to optimize it, I am working on that now. I am just curious if there is a better way to repopulate the listbox or if maybe another control would work better for my purpose of repopulating it with an array constantly.